# Query to select maximum of all minimum

Tags: mysql

I want to extract a row, with the max value in one field but is less than a certain value of that value;

Fore example,

`SELECT id,max(val) WHERE val<23`

Here, I need the value of the maximum of field `val` but which must be less than 23. This works and gives me, the maximum values, but the `id` field is not respective to that field, it provides the id of the first occurence.

What is the right query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about:

```
SELECT id, val FROM table WHERE val < 23 ORDER BY val DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT ID, VAL
FROM [TABLE]
WHERE VAL = (SELECT MAX(VAL) FROM [TABLE] WHERE VAL < 23)
```